# Meaningless characters before every build output in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Every time I use a build a file (any type of file – C++, python...), there's these funky characters that appear before the build output. Here's a screenshot, on the left, the console looks normal, on the right I cancelled a build to see whether it happened during or before the build. It's always the same characters.

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? I reinstalled Sublime from scratch (keeping my Packages and User Packages directories) and it's still happening. I'm running 3083 by the way.

Comment: The latest build is [3114](https://sublimetext.com/3). I strongly suggest you upgrade. When troubleshooting things like this, you need to disable all your plugins, ensure the problem disappears, then start adding them back one at a time until you find the culprit. It looks like shell escape sequences are being printed.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ANSIescape

Comment: I found the culprit, 2 lines in my .bash_prompt (sourced from .bashrc) which set the TERM variable (1) TERM='gnome-256color' and (2) TERM='xterm-256color'